# Django regex works only if the caret is typed into the address bar

Tags: python, django, rest

I'll preface this by saying that I'm a designer trying to learn to code. Now that that's out of the way…

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Attempting to access the admin with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`
serves up a 404 that looks like this:

> Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. ^admin
>
> The current path, admin/, didn't match any of these.

However, if I type the URL as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/^admin/`, which sanitizes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/%5Eadmin/`, I can see the admin dashboard.

Why is the regular expression not working here? Does something need to be imported?

Comment: Try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`, `^` is not normal character, it is `special regex character`

Comment: @RishabhChavhan That is the first thing that I tried, which serves the 404.

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: @mattermill While replacing `path` with `url` works as I am sure `url` accepts regex url filter. Try removing `^` from `path`

Comment: @Abhyudai `(3, 0, 0, 'final', 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for regex patterns there is re_path method in Django:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

or

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

don't mix them

Comment: I am only using `path()` in both of my `urls.py` files.